# Filter server superglobal

Tags: php

How do I properly filter `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` superglobal? Netbeans is giving me warnings and I realize unfiltered superglobals are a security threat but how do I do it?

Is this the correct way?

```
$root = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Comment: i don't think you need to filter `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, since it is set by PHP itself.

Comment: I am only using it as an menu include like so: `require ($root . "include/menu.php");` but it doesn't work

Comment: have a look at this [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#77307](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#77307)

Comment: the 'require' statement would look more like: require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/menu.php';

Answer (score 3):

```
$root = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
```

is correct way. I hope that will help.